# Splitting a file into chunks

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to split large files (3gb+) into chunks of 100mb, then sending those chunks through HTTP.
For testing, i'm working on a 29 mb file, size: 30380892, size on disk: 30384128
(so there is no use of a 100mb limit condition at the moment).

This is my code:

```
List<byte[]> bufferList = new List<byte[]>();
byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(file);
long length = fileInfo.Length;
int nameCount = 0;
long sum = 0;
long count = 0;

using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{    
    while (count < length)
    {
        sum = fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        count += sum;

        bufferList.Add(buffer);
    }

    var output2 = new byte[bufferList.Sum(arr => arr.Length)];
    int writeIdx2 = 0;
    foreach (var byteArr in bufferList)
    {
        byteArr.CopyTo(output2, writeIdx2);
        writeIdx2 += byteArr.Length;
    }

    HttpUploadBytes(url, output2, ++nameCount + fileName, contentType, path);
}
```

In this testing code, i'm adding each buffer I read into a list,
when finished reading i'm combining the buffer array into one complete array.
The problem is, the result I get (output2 size) is 30384128 (as size on disk), so the file that get received in the server is corrupted.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should basically add a `byte[] currentBuffer = new byte[4096]` *inside* the `while` loop and use `fs.Read(currentBuffer, 0, currentBuffer.Length)` instead

Comment: I'm also confused how this is even generating chunks (in any _meaningful_ sense). It is ultimately uploading the **entirety** of `output2` (which isn't a chunk). In that case, the vast majority of the code could be replaced with a call to `File.ReadAllBytes` - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readallbytes(v=vs.110).aspx .

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Thanks !

Comment: @mjwills It does generate chunks! Just to mix them together a couple of lines later, though...

Comment: You do see you are reading from zero each time sum = fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

Comment: @paparazzo The 0 doesn't mean it is reading from position 0 of the _stream_. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.read(v=vs.110).aspx and https://stackoverflow.com/a/6865956/34092 .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you keep adding the same `buffer` of size 4KB to `bufferList`. That's why the size of the file you receive matches the size on disk (it happens to be rounded to the nearest 4KB in your case).

A bigger problem with your code is that the data you send is wrong, because you keep overwriting the data in the `buffer`. If, for example, you send 200 chunks, it means that you send 200 copies of the last content of `buffer`.

The fix is relatively simple - make copies of the buffer before adding to `bufferList`:

```
bufferList.Add(buffer.Take(sum).ToArray());
```

This would fix the size problem, too, because the last chunk would have a smaller size, as represented by `sum` from the last call. Most importantly, though, `bufferList` would contain copies of the buffer, rather than the references to the buffer itself.